# Gradle: Link native library against existing external

Tags: java, gradle, native

I am building an API to create bridge between C, Puthon an JVM using swig and gradle as a build system. The problem is if I want to link swig generated source code against python headers, I need to include those headers into the build and I could not find a clear way to do so. Sadly, gradle currently lacks documentation for native builds.

From different sources I've composed following model definition:

```
model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            pythonHeaders {
                headers.srcDirs "$pythonPath/include"
            }

            jdkHeaders{...}
        }
    }

    components {
        transport(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            sources {
                lib library: 'pythonHeaders'
                c {
                    source {...}
                    exportedHeaders {...}
                }
            }
        }

    }

    toolChains {...}
}
```

This definition works for static library, but won't work for shared library because `python36.lib` is not on linker path.

`PreabuiltLibrary` interface has a field called `binaries`, but I see no way to add to it using DSL. Is there any standard way of fixing it or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Alexander Volanis [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/link-native-library-against-existing-external-headers/25565/2?u=altavir) seems to be working. In Anaconda, static libraries are placed in `libs` directory and dll-s in Anaconda root.